# Chromium based browser and Firefox omnibox: paste/type search keywords to go straight to google.com search results

Tags: javascript, performance, regex, cross-browser

**Functions and features:** paste/type search keywords to go straight to google.com search results pages - explicitly google.com NO google.TLD

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
function (details) {
var requestURL = details.url;
var re = new RegExp('^(http(?:s)?):\/\/www\.google\.(?:(?!com\/)[a-z]+\.?[a-
z]+)?/', 'gi');
return {
  redirectUrl: requestURL.replace(re, '$1://www.google.com/')
};
},
{urls: ['<all_urls>']},
['blocking']
);
```

#### Extension metadata

```
{
  "name": "__MSG_appName__",
  "description": "__MSG_appDescription__",
  "version": "1.0.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "default_locale": "en",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "homepage_url": "https://",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "omnibox-ncr.js"
    ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://www.google.*/*"
  ]
}
```

#### Concerns

- Performance and efficiency
- Functionality
- Does it effectively keep searches at google.com NOT google.TLD (without setting your google.TLD
  cookie)?

Comment: I feel like you should be a little more wordy in your questions. Like, make sentences, you aren't really limited on word count. It will make people want to answer your question :)

Comment: Well I allready sorted this out, however I'm sure I could get my regexp to be even more efficient.

Comment: Also I'm looking a way to save that regexp to chrome.storage.local but seems there are no advanced guides.